# React Bootstrap - Best practice for a conditional OverlayTrigger

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

We have a button that we want to have enabled or disabled depending on some condition. Furthermore, we want the hover effect of the button when disabled to display a tooltip explaining why it is disabled.

Currently, we have something like this:

```
export class NextButton extends React.Component {
    makePopover () {
        return (
            this.props.someCondition && <Popover>Please enter a title.</Popover>
        )
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <OverlayTrigger placement='top' overlay={this.makePopover()}>
                    {/* wrap this in a div so when the button is disabled, the popover still works */}
                    <div>
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => this.props.goToNextPage()}
                            disabled={this.props.someCondition}
                        >
                            Next
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, if we look closely at the `makePopover` function, if `someCondition` is false, `Popover` will not be rendered and `OverlayTrigger` throws an error if anything without an id is returned.

Therefore, to fix this we tried:

```
this.props.someCondition ? <Popover>...</Popover> : <span>...</span>
```

This helped but displayed other warnings:

> Warning: Unknown props `placement`, `arrowOffsetLeft`,
>   `arrowOffsetTop`, `positionLeft`, `positionTop` on  tag. Remove
>   these props from the element.

Now, instead of conditionally displaying the Popover, we could wrap the conditional around the entire `OverlayTrigger` itself, doing something like:

```
this.props.someCondition
?
    <OverlayTrigger>
        <Button>Next</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
:
<Button>Next</Button>
```

What is the best practice for how to deal with conditional tooltips?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem I thought the cleanest way to solve it is to use a conditional wrapper.

```js
const ConditionalWrapper = ({
    condition,
    wrapper,
    children,
}) => (condition ? wrapper(children) : children);


export class NextButton extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ConditionalWrapper
                    condition={this.props.someCondition}
                    wrapper={children => (
                        <OverlayTrigger
                            overlay={<Popover>Please enter a title.</Popover>}
                            placement='top'
                        >
                            {children}
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                        )}
                >
                    {/* wrap this in a div so when the button is disabled, the popover still works */}
                    <div>
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => this.props.goToNextPage()}
                            disabled={this.props.someCondition}
                        >
                            Next
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </ConditionalWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is Alexus answer in Typescript (mostly):

```
interface IConditionalWrapperProps {
    condition: boolean;
    wrapper: (children: React.ReactNode) => JSX.Element;
    children: JSX.Element;
}

const ConditionalWrapper = ({
    condition,
    wrapper,
    children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<IConditionalWrapperProps>) => (condition ? wrapper(children) : children);

export class NextButton extends React.Component {
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <ConditionalWrapper
                condition={this.props.someCondition}
                wrapper={children => (
                    <OverlayTrigger
                        overlay={<Popover>Please enter a title.</Popover>}
                        placement='top'
                    >
                        {children}
                    </OverlayTrigger>
                    )}
            >
                {/* wrap this in a div so when the button is disabled, the popover still works */}
                <div>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => this.props.goToNextPage()}
                        disabled={this.props.someCondition}
                    >
                        Next
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </ConditionalWrapper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was to override trigger property.

```
trigger={showOverlay ? ['focus', 'click'] : []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else wants to do something like this, this was my approach using TypeScript. I know it's a bit more verbose, but I think it's a little easier to understand and a little easier to use.

```
ConditionalTooltip.tsx

export interface IConditionalTooltipProps {
  // Boolean to determine if tooltip will show
  condition?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  // Necessary for keeping track of tooltips
  overlayPopoverId: string;
  overlayTriggerPlacement?: Placement,
  tooltipText?: string;
  // Default is hover. Other standard would be likely be 'click'
  triggerAction?: OverlayTriggerType | OverlayTriggerType[];
}

const ConditionalTooltip = ({
  condition,
  children,
  overlayPopoverId,
  overlayTriggerPlacement,
  tooltipText,
  triggerAction,
}: IConditionalTooltipProps) => {
  if (
    (condition === undefined || condition === true) && 
    tooltipText && tooltipText?.length > 0) {
    return(
      <OverlayTrigger
        trigger={triggerAction}
        placement={overlayTriggerPlacement}
        overlay={
          <Popover id={overlayPopoverId}>
            <Popover.Content>
              { tooltipText }
            </Popover.Content>
          </Popover>
        }
      >
        {/* Wrapping this in a div allows the overlay functionality to 
            behave even if the children component/s are disabled due to
            other functionality */}
        <div className="ConditionalOverlayTrigger">
          { children }
        </div>
      </OverlayTrigger>

    )
  }
  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment
    <>
      { children }
    </>
  )
}
```

and then

```
ButtonWithConditionalTooltip.tsx

const ButtonWithConditionalTooltip = () => (
  <ConditionalTooltip
    overlayPopoverId='Button-tooltip'
    overlayTriggerPlacement='auto-start'
    // If the tooltip is automatically generated or
    // empty for another reason, the tooltip won't show.
    tooltipText='A valid tooltip here'
    triggerAction='click'
    // If no condition passed, the component will determine
    // that there's no need to check and will display the tooltip.
    // It will only not show the tooltip if a condition equals false.
    condition={true}
  >
    <Button disabled={false}>
      My button that might need a tooltip
    </Button>
  </ConditionalTooltip>
)
```